# Flask form is not returned

Tags: forms, http, post, flask

I have read through a number of the discussions and tried various options ie request.form.get(), request.args.get(). I don't get anything passed from the form??

```
<div class="modal-body"> <h1> Affiliated Programmes </h1>
    <form id="grant_edit" action="" method="POST">                      
        <input type="hidden" id="popup_grant_id" name="grant_id"/>
        <div class="checkbox" id="programmes_container">
        </div><br/><br/>                    
        <button name="grant_submit" type="submit" value="programmes">              
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Update 
        </button>                           
    </form>
</div>
```

---

Button name is "grant_submit"
The "GET" returns the ID, the "POST" does not respond.

---

```
@app.route('/searchgrantprogs', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
# called by publication allocation using ajax
@login_required
def searchgrantprogs():

    grant_id = 0

    if request.method == 'GET':
        sql_grantprogs = """SELECT grant_id, programme_id 
                    FROM grants_programmes WHERE grant_id=:a;
                    """
        grantid = request.args.get('grant_id')
        print(grantid)
        r_grantprogs = list(conn.execute(text(sql_grantprogs), a=grant_id))
        return json.dumps([dict(r) for r in r_grantprogs])


    if request.method == 'POST':
        for gr in request.form.values():
            #form=grant_submit()
            grant_id = request.form.get('grantid')
            ##clustid=request.form['grant_submit']
            flash(request.form.get('grant_submit'))


    #return redirect(url_for('searchgrants'),)
    return render_template('search_grants.html', grant_id=grantid)
```

The error msg:

127.0.0.1 - - [21/May/2018 13:31:55] "GET /grants HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/May/2018 13:31:58] "GET /grants/search HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/May/2018 13:32:04] "GET /searchgrantprogs?grant_id=5141&_=1526905918527 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
5141
127.0.0.1 - - [21/May/2018 13:32:16] "POST /grants/search HTTP/1.1" 400 -

---

I cannot get the form details??

I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Do you have `method=post` attribute in your form? Post the full code for your form element.

Comment: Hi Mekicha, an article I read said to use type="submit not "post"

Comment: `action=""` the action attribute is supposed to provide the url where your form is posted. Is there a reason you have made an empty string?

Comment: Thanks, never noticed the action="" in any questions.

Comment: I don't see a flag to marked the question??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have grantid instead of grant_id

Switch

```
grant_id = request.form.get('grantid')
```

to:

```
grantid = request.form.get('grant_id')
```

Comment: Hi, apologies. I changed the grantid = request.form.get('grantid') to grantid = request.form.get('grant_id').

Comment: In the "GET", the id gets returned. In the "POST" it returns None ??